# Enabling ICS service to share internet connection via ad-hoc

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, ad-hoc-network

I am trying to start my ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) on my Win7 Professional, but it wont start. All I get is this message:

[image]

I understand the meaning of this message, but I need to set up ICS on my ad-hoc WiFi network. And it cant be done without this service. When I try to set up ad-hoc network and then click on "Turn on internet sharing" button, it tells me this: [image: http://prntscr.com/50w1t]

So I wanted to do it manually, according to the tutorial in Windows Help. There is something about Sharing tab in properties of my network connection. [image: http://prntscr.com/50w2y]

But I have no sharing tab in properties.

So I searched the internet and found that ICS service must be running for me to see this Sharing tab. Its like cursed circle :)

I have no external security programs like Norton or AVG or NOD.

What can I do?

Comment: All I can tell you is the same thing happens here, the service is not in use yet, so it just doesnt start yet. you have to have 2 "nets" to use it, one concidered to be local.  For Ad-Hoc, see the bottom of this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing <-- says vista, but should be similar.

Comment: I know that I HAVE two net cards, one LAN with internet connection and WiFi card, where I want to share :)

Answer (score 0):

ICS is disabled in some /windows 7 versions, particularly netbooks, there was a workaround but thats been disabled now too.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Posts like this are always better if you can cite a source where people can get more information and assess the reliability of the information.  Can you add that?  Thanks.